# Is there any working CMS extension for Spree 0.40.x (Rails 3)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, content-management-system, spree

I've been trying to add a basic CMS to my new Spree 0.40.x but I'm no getting any success. Documentation seems bare empty.

I've tried every extension listed [here](http://spreecommerce.com/extensions?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=cms) but I couldn't install some of them, others I did installed them, but seems they're using rails 2 deprecated methods.

Does any of you have been able to add a CMS to Spree under Rails 3? I don't mind if i need to use an older version of Spree, I just need a basic CMS.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why exactly will you need CMS?
If you require it to create static pages with WYSWYG editor then you can use spree-static-content extension https://github.com/spree/spree_static_content